# How to disable SharePoint 2013 alerts using CSOM

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, csom, alert

Using CSOM, I am able to retrieve the collection of alerts for a SharePoint Online site and disable each alert using the following code:

```
context.Load(context.Web.Alerts,
        collection => collection.Include(
            alert => alert.ID,
            alert => alert.Status
        )
);
context.ExecuteQueryWithRetry();

foreach (SP.Alert alert in context.Web.Alerts) {
    if (alert.Status == AlertStatus.On) {
        context.Load(alert);
        alert.Status = AlertStatus.Off;
        alert.UpdateAlert();
    }
}
context.ExecuteQueryWithRetry();
```

This doesn't work for SharePoint 2013 though. I get the error: "Field or property 'Alerts' does not exist".

Can this be done with CSOM?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 On-Premise CSOM Web object didn't support Alerts property.

Please use SharePoint Server Object Model below instead:

```
            using (SPSite site=new SPSite("http://sp/sites/MyDev"))
            {
                SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
                SPAlertCollection alerts = web.Alerts;
                foreach (SPAlert alert in alerts)
                {
                    alert.Status = SPAlertStatus.Off;
                    alert.Update();
                    web.Update();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Seems the same question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64807932/how-to-disable-sharepoint-2013-alerts-using-csom, If it helps to resolve the question, I suggest you could also accept as answer  to close this question. Thanks :-)